# Does Apple review apps while WWDC?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

3 days ago I submitted app for review, and it still waits for apple's review. Now there is a WWDC in Cupertino. Is it mean that Apple stopped reviewing apps while conference?

Comment: No, they still review apps, I've an app rejected 30 min before the WWDC keynote started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Store reviews are continuing during WWDC.

According to [Average App Store Review Times](http://appreviewtimes.com), reviews are continuing during WWDC. The [raw data](http://appreviewtimes.com/ios/raw-data) page shows reviews completed during the last 24 hours, such as [Stuart Cooper‏'s tweet](https://twitter.com/planetcoops/status/872004027692855297).